# delete and shift array elements

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, language-agnostic

Suppose I have 2 sorted arrays. One of them has the elements to delete from the other.
For example

```
  int array1[]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13};
  int delete[]={5,9,12};
```

How should I delete the elements indicated in the delete array from array1 and shift the rest in array1 efficiently?

I don't want to go over all the elements of array1 since some of them will be unchanged. So I figured starting from

```
  int j,i=0,n=0;
  for(j=delete[i+n];j<delete[i+1+n];j++){
      array1[i-n]=array1[i+1-n];
      n++;
  }
```

But I couldn't quite figure out how to do it right. Any ideas?

Comment: Any particular language ? If not then please tag as `language-agnostic`.

Comment: Is there any constraints? Like the range for values in array? Can you use different data structure for array1?

Answer (score 1):

Deleting any element from an array is an O(N) operation. You can do the following.

1. Initialize i = 0. count = 0.
2. Iterate through array1[] and search for element delete[i].
3. If you encounter an element array1[j] > delete[i], this means that delete[i] does not exist in array[]. Increment i to check for next element in delete array.
4. If you find an element array1[j] == delete[i], then increment count. and increment i.
5. Keep copying array1[j] to array1[j - count].

   array1[j - count] = array1[j];
6. Continue till the end of array1. At the end, resize array1 to be of size `size - count`.

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify a language. I would combine the arrays, make them a set and sort the result again.

```
set combined_set = new Set(array1 + array2)
array = new Array(combined_set).sort()
```

Comment: Duplicate elements would be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in two-step scanning on the `array1[]` and `delete[]`.

1. Scan these two arrays at the same time and remember the positions in `array1[]` whose values also appear in `delete[]`.
2. Based on the positions you obtained in the first step, you should know, for each value in `array1[]`, what positions should be after deleting values from `delete[]`. Then just copy to the right position. Done!

All the process can be done in **O(n)**.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming declarations like this:

```
var
   TgtArr : array of integer; // given- sorted array of elements to be modified
   TgtArrLen : integer;       // given- count of elements in TgtArr
   DelArr : array of integer; // given- sorted list of elements to be deleted
   DelArrLen : integer;       // given- count of elements in DelArr
```

And declaring these work variables:

```
var PutPtr, GetPtr, DelPtr : integer;  // local to deletion operation
```

This fragment will accomplish the deletion:

```
   DelPtr := 0;
   PutPtr := 0;
   for GetPtr := 0 to TgtArrLen-1 do begin
      if TgtArr[GetPtr]<>DelArr[DelPtr] then begin
         TgtArr[PutPtr] := TgtArr[GetPtr];
         PutPtr := PutPtr+1;
      end;
      if TgtArr[GetPtr]>=DelArr[DelPtr] then begin
         DelPtr := DelPtr+1;
         if DelPtr>=DelArrLen then break; // out of "for GetPtr" loop
      end;
   end;
   TgtArrLen := PutPtr;
```

(This is Delphi Pascal but you get the idea.)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to change the data structure, we can simply use two

> binary search

to search for the **lower bound** and **upper bound** of the element you want to delete. For example
array {1,1,2,2,3,3,3,4,5} and deleting element is 3 , so we have starting index and ending index is 4 and 6.

The next step is so simple, just collapse the segment specified by these two above indexes.

If you want to have faster performance, I suggest that you can use either **binary search tree**, or an array that store the **frequency** of elements.